# Can we move docker images from one repository to another repository inside same azure container registry

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-yaml, acr

I have docker images with some tags uploaded at one of my repository but I need to pick some images from that repository and move it to another repository. Both of them are residing inside a same azure container registry.

So far I have created the repository for storing the images but not able to pull those images

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```bash
az acr import -n MyRegistry --source sourceregistry.azurecr.io/sourcerepository:sourcetag
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-import